# iterating through elements on the same row

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, match

I have create a custom table with div and span and on this table I want to add values from an array itterating trough all span cells but I don't really know how to do that.

```
<div class="cust_table">
  <div id="mytab1" class="row">
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>

  <div class="row">
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I have this array:

```
var arry = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
   arry.push(i);
}
```

and I want to write all its values from 1 to 3 on span cells

```
var sel = document.querySelectorAll(.cell);
```

eventually matching position from array with a position from row cell.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(.cell);` should probably use a string instead...

Comment: What is the point of not using a table and utilizing it's rows and cells properties?

Comment: I wonder why not using <table> <tr> <td> instead of <div> and <span>?

Comment: @Redu,some1  the using of traditional <table> will bring some constraints and I never liked tables, I prefer more custom and dinamyc data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get elements by class name using **[`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** method and iterate over them with help of **[`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)** and **[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** methods. Where **[`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)** helps to convert `Nodelist` to array and **[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** helps to iterate over them.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('row')).forEach(function(ele) {
  Array.from(ele.getElementsByClassName('cell')).forEach(function(e, i) {
    e.textContent = arr[i];
  });
})
```

```html
<div class="cust_table">
  <div id="mytab1" class="row">
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**FYI :** **[`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)** method is introduced in ES6 so use [`[].slice.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for older browser and also check [polyfill option for `Array#forEach` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill).

---

**UPDATE :** 
For adding element randomly from array generate index using **[`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)** and update.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('cell')).forEach(function(e, i) {
  // generate index value within `0` and `arr.length - 1` and get element
  e.textContent = arr[Math.round(Math.random()*(arr.length-1))];
});
```

```html
<div class="cust_table">
  <div id="mytab1" class="row">
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Quiet quick! Just highlight support for __`Array.from()`__

Comment: The OP said he wants to write the contents of the array into the cell, matching the positions of the cells with the positions of the array. So I would say you need to do this `e.textContent = arry[i];`. But then the OP should be aware that his array has only 3 elements and there are 4 cells.

Comment: @Pranav C Balan, wow so easy and great :) ty!  I'm wondering, if I want to add array values on cells cells randomlly  ? matching positions from array with positions from cells ?

Comment: @Pranav C Balan ty I would like to have your js knowledge :)

Comment: @mcmwhfy : glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is a `</div>` is missing. I would do this job like;

```js
var rows = [...document.querySelectorAll(".cust_table .row")];
   table = rows.map(r => [...r.querySelectorAll(".cell")].map((c,i) => c.textContent = i+1));
console.log(table);
```

```html
<div class="cust_table">
  <div id="mytab1" class="row">
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
    <span class="cell">***</span>
  </div>
</div>
```